# Checkbox returns unchecked on form validation error - Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, validation

I am trying to submit simple form data along with multiple checkbox options.

But on form validation, these checkbox options return unchecked.

**View Code**

```
  <?php echo form_checkbox( array('id' => 'check_passport', 'name' => 'purchaser_meta[]','value'=>'Passport','class'=>'form-check-input' )); ?> 
  <?php echo form_label('Passport','check_passport');?>
  <?php  echo form_error('resident_passport');  ?>
```

**Controller Code**

```
$this->load->library('form_validation'); 
$this->form_validation->set_rules('purchaser_meta','Purchaser Type Meta','trim|required');
```

Though, it catches the values submitted from these check boxes.

Like `$this->input->post('purchaser_meta')` returns the array of values submitted   `array(3) {   [0]=>   string(8) "Passport"   [1]=>   string(4) "Visa"   [2]=>   string(11) "ID" }` .

Have a look on these images further.

**Submitting form with options checked**

[image]

**After submitting form / form_validation occurred**

[image]

**Problem**: I want these check boxes remain checked upon form validation errors. I don't know what i am missing here?

Comment: You need to assign $_POST data to $this->data["purchaser_meta"] and use this data in form to repopulate the form field after the validation.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit form that time you have get value of checkbox in return array.
So simple you have to just check through if...else..Condition for checked or unchecked.

```
$arrayval = array{"Passport","Visa","ID"};

if (in_array("Passport", $arrayval)){
  echo "Checked";
}
```

Put same code for all checkbox.

May be this things helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<?php echo form_checkbox( array('id' => 'check_passport', set_checkbox('purchaser_meta[]','check'), 'name' => 'purchaser_meta[]','value'=>'Passport','class'=>'form-check-input' )); ?>
```

Comment: i think you've missed something while writing code,becuase you're adding `set_checkbox('purchaser_meta[]','check')` inside the array without any index. Please review this. Thanks

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="purchaser_meta" value="1" <?php echo set_checkbox('purchaser_meta', '1'); ?> />
<input type="checkbox" name="purchaser_meta" value="2" <?php echo set_checkbox('purchaser_meta', '2'); ?> />

Answer (score 0):

//replace set_checkbox with this

set_checkbox('purchaser_meta', 'Passport', false)